# How to return nodes and related nodes with x number of relationships

Tags: neo4j

This query will find (:Tx) nodes that have more than 5 OUTPUT relationships.

```
match (t:Tx)-[r:OUTPUT]->(o) with count(r) as rc, t where rc > 5 return t
```

The problem I'm having is how do you also return the (o) nodes?  I've tried things like

```
match (t:Tx)-[r:OUTPUT]->(o) with count(r) as rc, t, o where rc > 10 return t, o
```

But I get 0 results with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `collect` function:

```
MATCH (t:Tx)-[r:OUTPUT]->(o)
WITH t, collect(o) as os, count(r) as rc
WHERE rc > 5
RETURN t, os
```